# Convert from LINQ to SQL query to SQL query

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, t-sql

I want to convert LINQ to SQL to SQL query. I know simple LINQ to SQL but don't know about more.

Given below is my Linq to Sql and I want to convert it into Sql query.

```
from objSql in objContext.DoctorNotes
join objCreatedU in objContext.Users on objSql.CreatedByUserFK equals objCreatedU.UserID into objCU
from tblC in objCU.DefaultIfEmpty()
join objModifiedU in objContext.Users on tblC.ModifiedByUserFK equals objModifiedU.UserID into objMU
from tblM in objMU.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new DoctorNoteBind(objSql)
{
    CreatedBy = tblC.UserName,
    ModifiedBy = tblM.UserName
}).ToList();
```

Comment: What is `objpredicate`? Or rather, where or how is it defined?

Comment: Set my Where clues in it. Plz ignore it If you want.I am confused for only "from tblC in objCU.DefaultIfEmpty()
join objModifiedU in objContext.Users on tblC.ModifiedByUserFK equals objModifiedU.UserID into objMU
from tblM in objMU.DefaultIfEmpty()
".

Comment: Why do you mix so hard query syntax and extension methods syntax? Also first OrderByDescending() and first ToList() are pointless and harmful (perform unnecessary operations spending resources producing no effect).

Comment: by the way...this isn't `Linq to SQL` it is `Linq to EntityFramework`

Comment: LINQ to Entities to be correct.

Comment: Hi I have edited my question. Now can u plz help me.

Comment: @abatishchev If you drop the first `.ToList()` then the `OrderByDescending()` makes sense (it should run the order by in SQL).

Comment: @Hitesh are you asking about how to convert THIS IQueryable, or to programatically convert IQueryables into SQL?

Comment: HI Aron I want a Sql query which is similar to this. I am confused about "from tblC in objCU.DefaultIfEmpty()
join objModifiedU in objContext.Users on tblC.ModifiedByUserFK equals objModifiedU.UserID". I don't know how to write this in Sql.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22770/How-To-LINQ-To-SQL-Transformation, May be help u.

Comment: @Aron: First OrderByDescending OP removed already (see edit history). And you're definitely right about removing first ToList() now. Also writing the whole query in consistent (say query) syntax.

Comment: Why We use " tblC.ModifiedByUserFK equals objModifiedU.UserID" inseted of "onjSql.ModifiedByUserFK equals objModifiedU.UserID". I don't know only this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .DefaultIfEmpty() are used to represent `LEFT JOIN`s (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.100).aspx). You'd expect the equivalent SQL to take the following form:

```
SELECT
    U1.UserName AS CreatedBy,
    U2.UserName AS ModifiedBy
FROM
    DoctorNotes DN
LEFT JOIN Users U1 ON
    U1.UserID = DN.CreatedByUserFK
LEFT JOIN Users U2 ON
    U2.UserID = DN.ModifiedByUserFK
-- WHERE ?
-- ORDER BY ?
```

Comment: Hi One more question. Why we use "join objModifiedU in objContext.Users on tblC.ModifiedByUserFK equals objModifiedU.UserID into objMU
from tblM in objMU.DefaultIfEmpty()
". what is the meaning of it.

Comment: That's how you express a `LEFT JOIN` using T-SQL. I mentioned that in the answer.

Comment: Why We use " tblC.ModifiedByUserFK equals objModifiedU.UserID" inseted of "onjSql.ModifiedByUserFK equals objModifiedU.UserID". I don't know only this part.

Comment: Loosely put, the expression `from tblC in objCU.DefaultIfEmpty()` represents the result set after "left-joining" `objSql` and `objCreatedU`. It combines all columns from `DoctorNotes` and `Users`. You'll want the next join to "append" to this result set hence the usage of `tblC` and not `objSql` in the second join expression

Comment: So How can I Use it in Sql? How can I get Object of combines all columns from DoctorNotes and Users into Sql and then how can I use it like " tblC.ModifiedByUserFK equals objModifiedU.UserID" ? Thanks